# Continue Azure B2C user journey on authentication failure

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am creating a custom user journey using Azure B2C Identity Experience Framework. My issue is that I want to continue the user journey when authentication fails. However, it appears that authentication failure is interpreted as an exception, which causes the journey to terminate.

This journey is intended to accommodate a just-in-time account migration process from a legacy idenity provider to B2C.

The flow that I am seeking to accomplish is:

1. Attempt authentication using a B2C sign in form
2. On authentication failure, query a REST API to determine if the user's email address exists in the legacy system
3. If email address exists, present user with a B2C signup form

Is this scenario even possible?

Comment: Hi Christok, have you considered checking locally first (not authenticating) to see if user exists. If user does exist then challenge login-noninteractive. If not, then query Rest?

Comment: Ultimately that might be the way I have to go with this but I'd rather not. The reason is overhead: if the user already has a B2C account then there is no reason to incur the resource cost of making an API call to retrieve information that I already know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a way to continue on full authentication failure, but you might not need to do that if just checking the existence of the user's account is enough.

You can check if the entered username exists in B2C without attempting authentication. Setting the RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist metadata to false allows the B2C policy to continue if the user does not exist in the directory. You can then take the entered username and continue with other technical profiles.

I used the below snippet as a validation technical profile and if the object ID is found, I run the *login-NonInteractive profile*, if not, I run a custom authentication profile

```xml
   <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-NoError">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <!-- Required claims -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_isMigrated" DefaultValue="False" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
    <!-- Optional claims -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea and sorry for the late reply. I still don't have this completely working to my satisfaction but the solution does seem to run a chain of validation techincal profiles and your snippet would be key to that. I'm calling it the accepted answer. Thanks!